# Custom parameter with Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to customizer my endPoint using Retrofit2 on Android but I have a doubt.

If I do that:

```
 @GET("Search") //i.e https://api.test.com/Search? 
      Call<Products> getProducts(@Query("one") String one, @Query("two") String two,    
                                @Query("key") String key)
```

My endPoint could be like this:

```
//-> https://api.test.com/Search?one=Whatever&two=here&key=SFSDF24242353434
```

I'm working with this endPoint:

```
// -> https://example.com/third-party-public/categories/category_id.json
```

If I use the same ideia as I explained above the result can be is:

```
@GET("/third-party-public/categories/")
Observable<List<Category>> getCategoryDetail(@Query(".json") String category_id);
```

The result could be:

```
// -> https://example.com/third-party-public/categories/.json=1
```

But I want that result

```
// -> https://example.com/third-party-public/categories/1.json
```

How can I setting my @query for get that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@GET("/third-party-public/categories/{category_id}.json")
Observable<List<Category>> getCategoryDetail(@Path("category_id") String category_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set a request with query it sets as query param '?'.

If the result you want is that you simply use it as in path:

```
@GET("Search/{fileUri}") 
      Call<Products> getProducts(@Path("fileUri") String fileUri);
```

You get the value it as "1.json".